# $this->Auth->identify(); returning false in cakephp 3.2

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I have done all the settings for login in cakephp 3.2,but while login it is returning false.

login function in usercontroller

```html
  public function login() {
        $this->viewBuilder()->layout('');
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();
            pj($user);//returning false
            if ($user) {
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }
    }
```

This function `$user = $this->Auth->identify();`  is always returning false.
Why can't i login?
In data base password is stored as

`$2y$10$4aD6Ye6YcmPGKgI/CmhJBO0E//9tV.KvhJIOFAhajyqt8vfxDVASC`

I am getting the email and password from `$this->request->data`.

Any suggestion will highly appreciate.
thank you in advance.

Comment: hi  please check the link, since you are using email instead of username so do some setting that are tell in this documentation:-http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html`

Comment: Under "Configuring Authentication Handlers" fourth example

Comment: Yes if  i am using username,then its working fine.@A-2-A

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please change like below:-

First in your controller add this code (best will be App controller):-

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'login',
            'plugin' => 'Users'
        ],
        'authError' => 'Did you really think you are allowed to see that?',
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => ['username' => 'email']
            ]
        ],
        'storage' => 'Session'
    ]);
}
```

And then use your code. It will be work properly.

Comment: i have tried this but in my case its return false every time

Comment: @SoubhagyaKumar  please ask a new question with your actual code and you will get answer for-sure

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem.  I am using `Cake 3.7`. This is for who use `routes`.

I created route in my routes file for login.

```
$routes->connect('/login',
        ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login'],
        ['_name' => 'login']
    );
```

Now when you use below code the `Auth` doesn't log you in and `identify()` returns false.

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'login'
        ],
        'loginRedirect' => ['what ... ever'],
        'logoutRedirect' => '/',
        'authError' => 'Please log in to view your account.',
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => ['username' => 'email']
            ]
        ],
    ]);
```

So ... you see... You have to call the route name for login attempt.

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'loginAction' => ['_name' => 'login'], // <= Here is Mr glitch 
        'loginRedirect' => ['what ... ever'],
        'logoutRedirect' => '/',
        'authError' => 'Please log in to view your account.',
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => ['username' => 'email']
            ]
        ],
    ]);
```

Really ?!!